# How can i change the properties of a UIView so it can be casted to UILable or UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uilabel

What i am trying to do is i read some content from a web service, each content has content type (text,image,button...).
I have to display dynamically the content in the UIView. So what i am trying to do is to create an IBoutlet UIView and check if the content type is a text i convert this uiview to UILable and display the text, if the content type is an image i convert the UIView to a UIImageView etc...
I need to work on the same UIView from the xib file, so how can i change the properties of the UIView to a UILable or a UIImageView.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "change" an UIView to be something different.

I suggest you dynamically add subviews to your view:

```
UIView *newView = nil;
switch (content type) {
    case 0: // text
        newView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        ((UILabel*)newView).text = @"someText";
        [newView sizeToFit];
    case 1: // button
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:...];
        [btn setTititle:@"Ttile" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal]; // assign all needed properties
        ...
        newView = btn;
    }
    case 2:
    ....
}
newView.frame = ... // calculate Frame using previously created content (e.g. remember y offset and add bounds.size.height after every iteration)
[self.view addSubView:newView];
....
```

Comment: 1 more question if i try to do newView=[[UILabel alloc]initWith... i can't add the text to the newView since newView is a UIView and not a UILabel... what i mean is that i can't write newView.text=@"someText";

Comment: edited to show 2 ways of referencing the var as their "real" types